# What is the equivalent attribute that can be used in spring-configuration file for @Qualifier annotation?

Tags: spring, spring-annotations

@Autowired annotation in Spring is equivalent to "autowiring="byName/byType/constructor" " in spring configuration file. Similarly, what is the equivalent attribute for @Qualifier annotation to avoid byType ambiguity??

Answer (score 0):

Good afternoon,

```
@Qualifier("nameOfBean")
```

In each bean of the same type, you need to use the annotation `@Component`. For example:

```
@Component("customerService")
public class CustomerService{
@Autowired
public CustomerService(@Qualifier("jdbcCustomerRepository") CustomerRepository customerRepository)
```

---

If there are 2 implementations of `customerRepository`, you need to define with `@Component` or any Stereotype annotation

```
@Component("jdbcCustomerRepository")
public class JdbcCustomerRepository implements CustomerRepository
```

---

```
@Component("jpaCustomerRepository")
public class JpaCustomerRepository implements CustomerRepository
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Francisco. My bad if the question isn't clear. Let me specify it more accurately. Is there any equivalent bean attribute available which can be used in the .xml spring configuration file to avoid the ambiguity, instead of using "Qualifier" or any other annotation? Can it be done in the .xml configuration file itself?

Answer (score 0):

`@Qualifier("nameOfBean")` is for autowiring beans by name, so in XML just do injection by name